# Hiding fields in Example Value but not in Model of Request Body in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

We are trying to achieve a scenario on the Swagger UI in the Body section. In the Requests section, can we have an Example Value JSON hiding one or more fields but the Model would still show those fields?

We are basically trying to reduce the number of fields in the request body but have all the fields visible in the Model.

For example, we would like to hide the `name` in the example here:

[image: Swagger UI - Example Value]

but still display the `name` in the Model here:

[image: Swagger UI - Model]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of technical details, instead copy and paste or type these into the post directly.

Answer (score 2):

To hide fields from auto-generated model examples in Swagger UI, you'll need to add a custom `example` for that model that includes only the fields you need.

```yaml
definitions:
  Pet:
    type: object
    properties:
      ...

    # Override model example that will be displayed in Swagger UI
    example:
      id: foo
      status: available
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. I tried your solution. Its working using the YAML but when I use @Example for a spring boot project, it does not work. I tried converting YAML generated by swagger editor to a spring server project and bring it up. It still does not work. Any advice please?

Comment: @Brams since you are using Spring specifically, please [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=swagger+spring) and include the annotations that you tried.