# Swagger how to display all the fields in the model but only some fields in the example value (SpringBoot project)

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger for API documentation. I am trying to reduce the number of fields in the request body but have all the fields visible in the Model.

I have searched all the related questions but could not find the solution. I tried [Hiding fields in Example Value but not in Model of Request Body in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647157/hiding-fields-in-example-value-but-not-in-model-of-request-body-in-swagger-ui) It works using YAML but I cant seem to find a solution as to how to make it work using the the annotations in a springboot project.

@Examples is not working as well. I tried:

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "U Input", dataType = "UInput", paramType = "body", 
examples = @Example(value = {@ExampleProperty(mediaType = 
"application/json", value = "{foo: whatever, bar: whatever2}")})
```